# FOSUserBundle's login form's route not found from network address

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

*Developing with Symfony (with FOSUserbundle) on WampServer in Windows 10.*

I must access my application through local network IP (not computer's local IP which would be 127.0.0.1) because at some point in the registration/authentication process, an external (national) authentication service has to be called.

My application works fine when I use *http://[my_network_ip]:81/* as well as *http://127.0.0.1:81/* , except for FOSUserBundle's login form. The excepted page is showing when using *http://127.0.0.1:81/login* , but when using *http://[my_network_ip]:81/login*, I get

> No route found for "GET /login/"

**Some configuration:**

*security.yml*

```
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory: ~
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        anonymous: ~
        logout: ~
        # activate different ways to authenticate

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate
        #http_basic: ~

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html
        form_login: ~
            #login_path: fos_user_security_login
            #check_path: fos_user_security_check
            #provider: fos_userbundle
            #csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            #default_target_path: /

encoders:
    AppBundle\Entity\FasUser: bcrypt
```

*routing.yml*

```
app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation

singlesingon_view:
    path:     '/authentication/singlesignon/'
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:AuthenticationSingleSignOn:view }

singlesingout_view:
    path:     '/authentication/singlesignout/'
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:AuthenticationSingleSignOut:view }

fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

*app_dev.php*

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],['[my_network_ip]','127.0.0.1', '::1'], true) || PHP_SAPI === 'cli-server')
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}
```

How can I get the login form working with *http://[my_network_ip]:81/login*

Comment: You can check `php app/console debug:router`

Comment: Since that route works locally, I don't expect to find any problem here. I just checked, but what do you expect it to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to have this page working by editing main *routing.yml* as follows:

```
(...)
fos_user_manual:
    path:     '/login/'
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:login }

fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

If tried `path:     '/login'` but that one didn't work.

So, this seems to work, I would still welcome comments or suggestions if there is a cleaner solution.